# Union All and Join in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

```
t1: CustID    CustName

       1        aaa
       2        bbb

t2: CustID    Tax1    Tax2

       1      5     10
       2      4     8
```

I need to write a query which brings as a result the following table

```
t3: CustID    CustName    TaxName    TaxValue

      1       aaa       Tax1       5
      1       aaa       Tax2       10
      2       bbb       Tax1       4
      2       bbb       Tax2       8
```

I was able to Union All

```
Select CustID,'Tax1' [TaxName], Tax1 [TaxValue]
from t2

union all

Select CustID,'Tax2' [TaxName], Tax2 [TaxValue]
from t2
```

but couldn't join here CustName from t1

Answer (score 1):

Just use a subquery:

```
select t2.custid, t1.custname, t2.taxname, t2.taxvalue
from ((Select CustID, 'Tax1' as [TaxName], Tax1 as [TaxValue] from t2
      ) union all
      (Select CustID, 'Tax2' as [TaxName], Tax2 as [TaxValue] from t2
      )
     ) t2 join
     t1
     on t1.custid = t2.custid;
```